Is this strengthening of Weyl's theorem correct?
Let's say we're given two real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, with $\alpha$ irrational. According to the simple version of Weyl's equidistribution theorem, the numbers $(\alpha m + \beta)_{m \in\mathbb{Z}}$ are equidistributed mod $1$. In particular, we can choose $m$ to make $\alpha m + \beta$ arbitrarily close to an integer.
Now, for a problem I'm working on, I require a stronger fact which I think might be true, but haven't been able to prove: That we can choose $m$ to make $\alpha m + \beta$ arbitrarily close to an integer $k$, so that also $m\times|\alpha m+\beta-k|$ is arbitrarily small.
I know that it can't be arbitrarily small easily - if we set $\beta=0$ for example, Thue-Siegel-Roth for $\alpha$ tells us that $m\times|\alpha m-k| < \frac1{m^\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ has only finitely many solutions, but does not exclude something like $m\times|\alpha m-k| < \frac1{\log m}$.
On the other hand, for any fixed $k$, according to the stronger version of Weyl's theorem, $m(\alpha m+\beta-k)$ is also equidistributed mod $1$. This is what makes me think the conjecture could be true - just sounds like there should be some $k$ so that $m(\alpha m+\beta-k)$ is small, and also $\lfloor\alpha m+\beta\rceil=k$.
Does anyone have any idea on how to prove or disprove this?

Wouldn't a badly approximable $\alpha$ (such as the reciprocal of the golden ratio) satisfy $m \cdot \left|\alpha m - k\right| > c$ for all integers $m, k > 0$?
